# database design for millions of rows

Tags: database-design, bigdata

I have an application that has users and buttons, each has a unique ID. I created a user_tbl and button_tbl.

When there are not much of buttons or users everything goes well, but what when there will be hundreds of millions of users and buttons? users and buttons will be spread over many tables...
So I figured out that I have to create multiple tables and name them tbl_0, tbl_1 and so on, then generate user IDs, when IDs that start with 0 will be stored in user_tbl_0, IDs that start with 1 will be stored in user_tbl_1 and so on. The same goes for the buttons.

Now, queries are performed according to buttons or to users, i.e. sometimes I need to query all USERS that are assigned to a certain BUTTON and sometimes query all BUTTONS that are assigned to a certain USER.
I created a user_buttons_tbl in which each row contains user ID and button ID that is assigned to the user. Then again, when there is only one such table, there's no problem, but at some point I will have to create additional tables and name them user_buttons_tbl_0, user_buttons_tbl_1 and so on according to the user ID.

The Problem:
That helps me only when I query for all BUTTONS for a certain USER. In such case I can query from the appropriate table (0, 1, ...) according to the user ID, but When I need to query all USERS for a certain BUTTON I need to query all of those user tables because this button might have users that their IDs starts with 0, 1, 2 and so on.

Possible solution:
Create button_users_tbl_0, button_users_tbl_1 and so on (just like user_buttons_tbl), in which the  button ID and not the user ID will be the key to decide in which table to store the record (tbl_0, tbl_1, ...). That can serve me when I need to query all USERS for a certain BUTTON.

That means that when I assign a button to a user, I need to insert the record to the appropriate user_buttons_tbl according to the user ID and to the appropriate button_users_tbl according to the button ID so it's kind of 2 times storage space for the same data.

My questions:

1. What if I have another data type besides USERS and BUTTONS? like LINKS where each link is assigned to a certain button and each link has a link ID? This complicates things further and might require additional "duplicated" tables.
2. Maybe I should add tabels on tables without even naming them with 0, 1, 2 and so on, and query them all each time... It sounds as a bad practice, but I don't know... maybe that's how it's done. Is it?
3. What is the right thing to do here? What is considered as a good database design practice for big data with such data crosses? Are there any other solutions?

I will greatlly appreciate you answer, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The general rules for performance optimization are:

- Don't optimize prematurely
- Measure before you start.

If you're using a SQL database, you should start by building a properly normalized database schema, and start tweaking it for performance only when you actually start running into performance problems. That way, you actually know where the bottle-necks are. If you start out by designing a schema based on what you *think* the bottle-necks are going to be, and reality turns out to be different, you're going to have a bad time. In any case, hundreds of millions of rows aren't necessarily a problem for a well-designed SQL database.

If you don't need the power of a relational database in the first place, you can look at NoSql solutions like Cassandra, CouchDB or one of the many other solutions. These have a reputation for performance and scalability, but they require a bit more effort to manage your data.

Comment: Thanks Rik. I see what you're saying and it sounds logical. However, I would like to be prepared at least with the ID format so whatever bottle necks I will experience, the IDs infrastructure will support easy scalability. Is it right to use the AI option, or maybe generate a smart ID like XYZ12345678 so it will give me more flexibility later on?

Comment: Smart ID's give you *less* flexibility, not more. 64-bit integers have 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 distinct values. You don't need to scale bigger than a 64-bit ID number.